# Multithreading issue with UDP Client class implemented using C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, udpclient

Since I am committed to develop some little audio applications that share audio content over network through the UDP protocol, I am currently drafting the code for a UDP Client class.
This mentioned class should receive the audio content of the other clients connected to network and also send the audio content processed on the local machine; all these contents are exchanged with a server, that works as a kind of content router.
Since audio content is generated by a `process()` method that is periodically called by the audio application, in order to not loose packets, each audio application should have a kind of UDP listener that is independent from the `process()` method and that should always be active; they should only share a buffer, or memory allocation, where audio data can be temporary saved and later processed.

Taking all this into account, I coded this method:

```
void udp_client::listen_to_packets() {
    while (udp_client::is_listening) {
        if ((udp_client::message_len = recvfrom(udp_client::socket_file_descr, udp_client::buffer, _BUFFER_SIZE, MSG_WAITALL, (struct sockaddr*) &(udp_client::client_struct), &(udp_client::address_len))) < 0) {
            throw udp_client_exception("Error on receiving message.");
        }
        std::cout << "New message received!" << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "Stop listenig for messages!" << std::endl;
}
```

As you can see, the function uses `udp_client::buffer` that is the shared memory allocation I previously mentioned. In order to let it be always active, I was thinking to start a new thread or process at class construction and stop its execution at class destruction:

```
udp_client::udp_client():
  is_listening(true)  {
  std::cout << "Constructing udp_client..." << std::endl;
  std::thread listener = std::thread(udp_client::listen_to_packets);
}

udp_client::~udp_client() {
  std::cout << "Destructing udp_client..." << std::endl;
  udp_client::is_listening = false;
}
```

Of course, the above listed code doesn't work and as @user4581301 suggested, the `listener` and `is_listening` variable definitions have been moved to class attributes:

```
private:
  std::atomic<bool> is_listening;
  std::thread listener;
```

Furthermore the constructor and destructor have been modified a little:

```
udp_client::udp_client():
  listener(&udp_client::listen_to_packets, this),
  is_listening(true)  {
  std::cout << "Constructing udp_client..." << std::endl;
}

udp_client::~udp_client() {
  std::cout << "Destructing udp_client..." << std::endl;
  udp_client::is_listening = false;
  listener.join();
}
```

Unfortunately, `g++` still returns an error, saying that there are not constructors with two arguments for the `std::thread` class:

> error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'std::thread'
>     listener(&udp_client::listen_to_packets, this)

So, what should I modify to make the code work properly?

Here you can see the implementation of the class (hoping that this link is allowed for Stack Overflow rules):
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/lzxlp3tyvoncvxo/AAApN5KLf3YAsOD0PV7wJJO4a?dl=0

Comment: Sounds like this doesn't really have anything to do with UDP and everything to do with calling a member function in a `std::thread`. You need to get the address of the function and provide an instance of the class: `std::thread listener = std::thread(&udp_client::listen_to_packets, this);` But note that `listener` is an Automatic variable scoped to the constructor. When the constructor ends, that thread will be destroyed and if the thread hasn't finished running the program will terminate. You probably want to make `listener` a `private` member variable and `join` it at the end of destructor.

Comment: @user4581301, if I'm not wrong (I'm a newbie with multithreading), `join` makes the parent thread wait the complete execution of the child thread, is it right? If yes, the thread that I would like to start should be active for all the life cycle of the class. In fact, the `while` block inside `listen_to_packets` is controlled by a class variable that I set to `false` only during the destruction of the class.

Comment: Yes, you'll need the thread as a member, flag it to shutdown in the destructor, and wait for it to shutdown via `join`. If you're new to multithreading, be sure your flag variable is `atomic` or protected by a mutex along with any other shared data you intend to use.

Comment: Don't switch to pthread. You're on the right lines. (Can't tell offhand what the error is; usage looks right.) By the way, your members are initialized in the wrong order.

Comment: [Unable to reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5833edffaf7d521e) _(you may not witness a delay due to coliru's caching)_. Show us your [MCVE].

Comment: Okay, I am going to update the question including a more in depth explanation of what I am willing to do.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, `g++` returns the same error above mentioned until I add the `-std=c++11` option!

Comment: That doesn't sound right. `std::thread` shouldn't be recognised _at all_ pre-C++11! What is your compiler version please? And we do still need that [MCVE]

Comment: Here is what `g++ --version` prints on terminal:
`Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin`